# Why is the custom layer decomposed into several operations in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I want to get the weights of my custom layer, but I couldn't get them by model.layer().get_weights()[X].
So I checked the layers of the model, it seems that the custom layer is decomposed into several operations and no weights can be found in these layers.

Here is the custom layer code

```
class PixelBaseConv(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(PixelBaseConv, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # kernel_shape: w*h*c*output_dim
        kernel_size = input_shape[1:]
        kernel_shape = (1,) + kernel_size + (self.output_dim, )
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=kernel_shape,
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(PixelBaseConv, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        # output_shape: w*h*output_dim
        outputs = []
        inputs = K.cast(inputs, dtype="float32")
        for i in range(self.output_dim):
            #output = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([inputs, self.kernel[..., i]])
            output = inputs*self.kernel[...,i]
            output = K.sum(output, axis=-1)
            if len(outputs) != 0:
                outputs = np.dstack([outputs, output])
            else:
                outputs = output[..., np.newaxis]
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(outputs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape + (self.output_dim, )
```

Here is part of the model structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct9u7.png)

I tried different ways to obtain the weights but due to the strange layers, failed.

Expected: the first five layers are replaced with single layer which has a trainable kernel. Weights can be get directly by get_weights()

I listed weight list length of the first 10 layers and printed weight of layer 1 by following codes

```py
for i in range(len(model.layers)):
    print("layer " + str(i), len(model.layers[i].get_weights()))
print(model.layers[1].get_weights()[0])
```

and got the result and error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XscNX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQBNX.png)

Comment: Your custom layer does have weights, see the self.add_weight call? You did not provide evidence of these missing weights.

Comment: You can see the image of the model structure, and my custom layer consists of several operation layers without weights information. When I used model.layer(x).get_weights()[0] to get weights, there was an error: index out of range, because the length of these layers are all 0.

Comment: I added the information of missing weights.

Answer (score 0):

I found why this problem occurred.
I wrote the custom layer by

```
import tensorflow.python.keras
```

while using other keras layers and creating the model by

```
import tensorflow.keras
```

I think these two libraries may not be compatible, so my custom layer was splitted into several operation layers. Thus, weights cannot be obtained and updated.
I changed all imports to tensorflow.keras, now everything goes well.